# Preseeding debian install - EFI

Tags: debian, uefi, preseed

The EFI partition is formatted in ext4 during the setup of debian whereas it should be vfat.

I am trying to preseed the install of debian jessie and I can't get it working since the UEFI partition is formatted in ext4 (got information with blkid). I can't get it formatted in vfat.

My preseed for partitionning is the following:

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                        \
 boot-root ::                                               \
         1 1 1 free                                      \
                 $gptonly{ }                             \
                 $primary{ }                             \
                 $bios_boot{ }                           \
                 method{ biosgrub }                      \
         .                                               \
         512 100 512 vfat                                \
                 $gptonly{ }                             \
                 $primary{ }                             \
                 method{ efi }                           \
                 format{ }                               \
                 $lvmignore{ }                           \
                 mountpoint{ /boot/efi }                 \
         .                                               \
         ...
         .
```

And I get the following error: 
"Failed to mount vfat filesystem on /boot/efi"
(error message translated from FR, sry)

> Of course, its an ext4 fs...!

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found a workaround, I had to duplicate the efi partition.
I don't know why but it does work so that suits me.

Maybe there is a ticket to open at debian or somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the vfat type with fat32

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!
As I wrote hereunder, I did find a workaround so it's ok now